# How to create folder in /var/mobile/Documents for jailbroken iOS device?

Tags: objective-c, directory, jailbreak

my app need to download file, but I would like to store all those files into a rep in /var/mobile/Documents.
To create this folder I use :

```
NSString *path;
    path = [@"/var/mobile/Documents/" stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myFolder"];
    NSError *error;
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])    //Does directory already exist?
    {
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:path
                                       withIntermediateDirectories:NO
                                                        attributes:nil
                                                             error:&error])
        {
            NSLog(@"Create directory error: %@", error);
        }
    }
```

But it's don't work, can you tell me why ? 
Thank

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't get the path to the documents folder that way. Use this instead:

```
NSString *dir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
path = [dir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myFolder"];
```

You shouldn't hard code system paths, except perhaps for `/dev/null` and `/dev/random`. Apple can change them at any time in a future iOS version.

---

BTW `/var/mobile/Documents/` isn't writable anyway, because if it were it would interfere with other apps that also write there.

Comment: I think it's writable because my app download the files in it, but I would like to add a subfolder.

Comment: No, it is not. You can only write to it on jailbroken devices. Are you sure your app downloads to it? Can you write those files?

Comment: My iPhone is Jailbroken and my app is on Cydia.

Comment: I don't know anything about developing for jailbroken devices, sorry.

Comment: Cydia work with debian package so, I will use the /postinst file to create the directory in /var/media/Downloads (I think this is the more easy way to do that).

Comment: Sorry @WTP'-- but your answer is incorrect for the question asked.  Jailbreak apps installed via Cydia do not have an NSDocumentDirectory.  They must write to /var/mobile/Documents/.  Its best practice to have your jailbreak app immediately create /var/mobile/Documents/YOUR_APP_NAME upon launch, and use that path to save files.  At the bottom of the following link is an explanation http://thebigboss.org/hosting-repository-cydia/submit-your-app/compile-for-cydia-submission